# How to write regex for 'List-Unsubscribe'?

Tags: postfix, regex

I have found that many emails that are coming in my spam contain something like this one:

```
List-Unsubscribe: <http://blablabla.eu/ru/unsubscribe/do?hash=78943759789437589>
```

So far I want to `REJECT` all emails containing in List-Unsubscribe: `ru/unsubscribe/do?hash=`

Is it right like this: `/^List-Unsubscribe:.*ru/unsubscribe/do?hash=/ REJECT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those slashes `/` and question marks `?` are going to interfere with the regex syntax. Try:

```
/^List-Unsubscribe:.*ru\/unsubscribe\/do\?hash=/ REJECT
```

Try yourself with something like https://regexr.com/

Comment: More specifically, those slashes will be treated as terminating the regex (because, in this context, the regex is defined as "the stuff between the slashes) and so you need to escape them with backslash. In addition, the question mark will be interpreted as "previous character is optional" unless you escape it.